# Turning negative values into 0s in a list that also has letters

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, nested-lists

So here is the deal. I have nested lists - most part of the list is numbers but at the end they have letter that is being used to identify the list.

For instance:

```
alist = [[0, -2, 3, 5, 10, -20, 'a'],[0, -4, 3, 30, 40, -15, 'a']]
```

I want this to be transformed into:

```
alist = [[0, 0, 3, 5, 10, 0, 'a'],[0, 0, 3, 30, 40, 0, 'a']]
```

I know how to turn negative values into 0s using if statements and for loops, but I don't know how to do this in a neat way when letters are also present in the list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
alist = [[0, -2, 3, 5, 10, -20, 'a'],[0, -4, 3, 30, 40, -15, 'a']]
res = [[j if (isinstance(j, str) or (j > 0)) else 0 for j in i ]for i in alist]
print(res)
```

or

```
alist = [[0, -2, 3, 5, 10, -20, 'a'],[0, -4, 3, 30, 40, -15, 'a']]
res = []

for i in alist:
    temp = []
    for j in i:
        if isinstance(j, str) or (j > 0):
            temp.append(j)
        else:
            temp.append(0)
    res.append(temp)

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 0, 3, 5, 10, 0, 'a'], [0, 0, 3, 30, 40, 0, 'a']]
```

**Note:**

- use `isinstance` to check the object.

Comment: Thanks, I was going in the right direction but falling miserably. Cheers!